# writing dask dataframe to S3 using string IO

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boto3, dask

I have a dask dataframe `dask_df` which I want to store directly to S3 without converting into pandas (`dask_df.compute()`) as it's too large. The problem is that string IO is throwing error when I try to do the following :

```
import boto3
from boto3 import session, client
import dask.dataframe as dd
import datetime

today = date.today()    

client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'test-bucket'
prefix = 'foldername/'
csv_buffer = StringIO()
dask_df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
filename = 'filename_{}.csv'.format(today)

response = client.put_object(
    ACL = 'private',
    Body = csv_buffer.getvalue(),
    Bucket = bucket,
    Key = prefix+filename
    )
```

#### This is the error I'm getting -

raise TypeError(*"url type not understood: **%s"*** % urlpath)

TypeError: url type not understood: <_io.StringIO object at 0x7f830e6b5550>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docstring](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_csv) does **NOT** say that you can write to a StringIO; indeed, wouldn't you expect this to fill up your memory?

Fortunately, Dask has done the work for you, and you can do

```
dask_df.to_csv("s3://test-bucket/foldername/filename_*.csv")
```

and ... that's it.

See also: [remote data and Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/remote-data-services.html)

Comment: Actually the problem with to_csv('s3...') is that s3fs is posing some problems and always give me errors like `AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'current_task'`

Comment: It seems like you might need python 3.7. I'll look into whether the same thing can be achieved in python 3.6.

Comment: It looks like it was available as [Task.current_task](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=current_task#asyncio.Task.current_task). Strictly speaking, the line is not necessary. This is a bug for fsspec, but the answer given here I think should be marked correct.

Comment: so before using stringIO i was trying to run using s3fs only. this is my exact error - 
`File "/users/abc/aws-staging/aws/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 90, in maybe_sync
    return _run_until_done(func(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/users/abc/aws-staging/aws/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 21, in _run_until_done
    task = asyncio.current_task()
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'current_task'`

Comment: https://github.com/intake/filesystem_spec/issues/425